# Unpredictable behaviour of JTextField removing ASCII char

Tags: java, encryption, javafx, ascii

I have been working on some application which encrypts data using 3DES algorithm, but when I tried to make some UI for it I faced some really strange behaviour, after I encrypt data and represent it back again as ASCII I get:

```
String encryptedASCII = ;nÆ«»Ë?&]º²ÿ
```

and following array of bytes for it:

```
[-62, -118, 59, 110, -61, -122, -62, -85, -62, -69, -61, -117, 4, 7, -62, -105, 63, 38, 93, -62, -70, -62, -78, -61, -65]
```

But when I use:

```
textField.setText(encryptedASCII)
```

and once again get it from there to decrypt:

```
textField.getText()
```

I got:

```
;nÆ«»Ë?&]º²ÿ
```

and bytes for it:

```
[-62, -118, 59, 110, -61, -122, -62, -85, -62, -69, -61, -117, -62, -105, 63, 38, 93, -62, -70, -62, -78, -61, -65]
```

What makes it two missing bytes [4, 7] from the array of bytes which I got before I set up text field with its representation as ASCII.

Is there anything what I'm missing here ? I can't decrypt it back again having data changed over setting it up in text field.

Comment: That's what you get when you consider that arbitrary bytes and encoded characters are the same thing, and that any sequence of bytes is a valid sequence of encoded characters. It's not. If you want printable characters from a byte array, use Base64 encoding.